# JAX-RS and Bean Validation in Kotlin: make @NotNull obsolete

Tags: kotlin, jax-rs, quarkus, resteasy, bean-validation

The following JAX-RS code in Kotlin sufficiently well establishes that `myParam` is mandatory.

```
@GET
fun hello(@QueryParam("myParam") myParam: String): String = myParam
```

At Kotlin-level `myParam` is not nullable. Yet, for a JAX-RS implementation like RESTEasy (on Quarkus in my case) this is irrelevant. I am still required to add an additional `@NotNull` Bean Validation annotation. To a Kotlin developer this is counter-intuitive as I'm expressing the same semantics twice (`myParam` is mandatory).

Comment: The Kotlin compiler emits a `null` check into the method automatically. If you want a duplicate `null` check (by Bean Validation), you need to add a duplicate annotation. That said, you can file a feature request for the "Hibernate Validator" component in the Quarkus issue tracker: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues -- but note that it isn't as easy as it sounds, because Kotlin adds its `@NotNull` annotations on a lot of places and transforming all of them to Bean Validation annotations could easily lead to pretty big overhead.

Comment: Yep, I agree with your assessment (wrt overhead). The downside of "forgetting" to add  Bean Validation `@NotNull` is the system throwing a `NullPointerException` which leads to server error instead of _client_ error. Hence, the API response has the wrong semantics.

Comment: In theory I could probably use a `ExceptionMapper` and introspect every NPE to see whether I should treat it as a client error. I'd have to get the triggering class & function from the stacktrace and start introspecting them for e.g. JAX-RS annotations etc. Not sure if this would work with Quarkus native artifacts, though.

Comment: Two immediate issues I see: class would have to be registered for reflection and it would have to be available in the `ExceptionMapper` through `Class.forName`. So, no dice, likely.